# PHP bypass max_script_execution by repeatedly calling itself by header location

Tags: php

I've got a script that does heavy database manipulation.

it worked all okay untill i reached a higher number of databases where to fire the manipulations. now i collide with the max_script_execution timeout.

is it possible to handle the databases one by one when i redirect to the same script with a param for the next db by header location?

or would this not affect the max_script_execution and timeout anyway?

Comment: You should not be doing long-running jobs through a browser in the first place. Use a cron-job or other sort of "background" task which is not restricted by web server enforced timeouts. Not to mention that it drains resources from the web server itself.

Comment: Redirections are not reliable. A user agent may choose not to (or simply fail to) load the next page. If you want the manipulation to complete reliably, you should use a server-side worker, which completes commands from a queue filled by the user.

Comment: That could work, but would be very fragile, as it would rely on the user and there browser behaving, which cannot be guaranteed. A better option would  probably be to use php cli via exec, as that does not usually have timeout limitations. Another option would be to just increase the timeout if you have the permissions to do so

Comment: it is accessed by a webinterface where you can chose different actions. and i guess i cannot go through limitations with an exec to run the script server side due to shared hosting limitations

Comment: In that case, you could still opt to divide the operation into chunks, but I think it's a better solution if you somehow poke that script yourself. This avoids some of the aforementioned issues with failing clients. If your hosting solution supports cronjobs, you should really consider using them.

Comment: Okay maybe i need to use two groups of databases. DB a to ? and ? to z

Comment: If you think you have to split your database, you have either a far too large database for your available processing power (unlikely) or you're processing it inefficiently (much more likely). Maybe it's a better idea to ask a new question: how can you optimise your operations?

Comment: No. i do the manipulation on about 30 databases. i meant to split the action to do ~15 databases per run and run it twice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

Add this line in the top of your php script.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

But, one thing remember, it is not a good trick to follow. You should check you script to minimize the execution time.

Comment: max limit is given by hoster

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time): this will not work when PHP is running in safe mode, and may be overridden by the webserver's timeout behaviour. Furthermore, it doesn't solve OP's underlying problem.